# Etale cohomology and restricted direct product

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

[migrated to mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/161734/etale-cohomology-and-restricted-direct-product]

$\newcommand{\h}{\operatorname{H}}$
Let $k$ be a global field, $A$ an abelian variety over $k$, and $\mathbf A$ the ring of adeles of $k$. One defines the *Tate-Shafarevich group* of $A$ by 
$$
  Ш(A) = \ker\left(\h^1(k,A) \to \prod_v \h^1(k_v,A)\right)
$$
where $\h^1(-)$ is etale cohomology, and we interpret $A$ as a sheaf on the etale site of $k$. In fact, the image of $\h^1(k,A)$ lands inside of the smaller group 
$$
  \prod_v' (\h^1(k_v,A), \h^1(\mathfrak o_v,A))
$$
(restricted direct product). This makes sense because for almost all $v$, $A$ has good reduction at $v$.

> My question is, do we have 
>   $$
>   \h^1(\mathbf A_k,A) \simeq \prod_v' (\h^1(k_v,A), \h^1(\mathfrak o_v,A))?
> $$

In that case, we could define $Ш(A) = \ker(\h^1(k,A) \to \h^1(\mathbf A_k,A))$. 
I'm a little worried because $\mathbf A_k$ is pretty horrible when considered as a commutative ring, so its etale site will probably not be easy to manage.

**Edit:** Just so its clear, this was inspired by Poonen's lectures at the most recent AWS.

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Etale cohomology and restricted direct product](https://mathoverflow.net/q/161734).